# Uneven section header size in static UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, static, uinavigationcontroller

I've created a simple static `UITableView` which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I don't understand why the height of the first section header is greater than that of the height of the section header after the first section. I want the height of the section headers to be the same.

Note: I'd like to do everything in the Storyboard if possible.

[image: UITableView]

Comment: That's not the height of the first section header. There is a space above the first section when using static UITableView.

Comment: Thanks @Rick. Do you know of a way to remove that extra space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this just in Storyboard. The only way I have been able to get things looking the way I want is to implement something like;

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

if (section==0)
{
    return 25;
}
else
if (section==1)
{
    return 35;
} // etc etc
```

And then, in Storyboard, adjust the Table View Size, Section Height values.

Comment: return section == 0 ? 35 : 25;